# Is there a way to automatically delete data from database after unit testing?

Tags: php, jquery, jestjs

Is there a way to automatically delete data from database after unit testing?

Comment: Alternative to what?

Comment: So alternative cleanup to clean up?

Comment: to put it simply sir. i need an alternative way to automatically delete dummy data it's because it's kinda hassle every time i inserted a data  id go to my database and delete all dummy.

Comment: Why is this tagged jquery?

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin > tablename > operations > Empty the table (TRUNCATE)